# Batch file for uninstallation of application

Tags: c#

I have created a batch file to uninstall my application. The code is:

```
//
@ECHO OFF 

msiexec /x {8DF8694A-6B64-4477-8B6B-1F9D676107E7}

//
```

It works fine, but when I run this file the cmd promt is open. I don't want to open the command promt - what can I do?

Comment: First of all you have to include/add this **batch file**  into your deployment project's Application folder (if you are using VS setup project wizard) and add short-cut of this batch file into User's program menu.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the nature of the batch file interpreter. It is going to put a console window up, and include it in the taskbar.

Instead of a batch file ship a shortcut whose target is your msiexec command. It's just a different way to invoke the command but it won't lead to any windows being shown, beyond what msiexec may show.

Comment: How can i do this? can u give me the code or step for how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Your install program will typically create such a shortcut for you. Which install program are you using to create your msi?